# Connected, but no internet when resuming -- works after reboot

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, cinnamon, connectivity

I can connect to known networks, but do not have internet upon resuming (from suspension). The connection will be fine after a reboot.

I am running Mint 18.2, kernel 4.10.0-35-generic.

Edit: It is inconsistent, but I think it happens possibly exclusively when I change connections/locations.